# If: XElement Exists, Else Create new one

Tags: c#, find, xelement

My XML File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SimpleKD>
  <player name="Tardis">
    <kills>0</kills>
    <deaths>0</deaths>
    </player>
</SimpleKD>
```

First off, I need to check if the username "Tardis" exists in the xml `.element("player").attribute("name")`.

If it doesn't, i need to create it with kills and deaths at zero.
If it does, I need to read kills and deaths and set them to variables.

I have been using `XElement` to try and do this.. Thanks!

Code used to write the XML:

```
public static string username = "Tardis";
public static int kills = 0;
public static int deaths = 0;

........

XElement Players = new XElement(
                      "SimpleKD",
                      new XElement("player",
                          new XAttribute("name", username),
                      new XElement("kills", kills),
                      new XElement("deaths", deaths)));
```

Comment: Side note -- you should look into XML Serialization and LINQ.  You can save a lot of heartache vs. manually parsing XML.

Comment: @George: `XElement`, `XDocument` and co. were written specifically to play well with LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Player` class:

```
private static Player GetPlayer(string name, XElement simpleKD)
{
    var playerElem = simpleKD.Elements("player")
                             .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == name);
    if (playerElem == null)
    {
        simpleKD.Add(new XElement("player",
                                  new XAttribute("name", name),
                                  new XElement("kills", 0),
                                  new XElement("deaths", 0)));
        return new Player(name);
    }

    return new Player(name,
                      (int)playerElem.Element("kills"),
                      (int)playerElem.Element("deaths"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument xmlfile= new XmlDocument();
xmlfile.Load("FileName.xml");
XmlNode node = xmlfile.SelectSingleNode("//SimpleKD");
XmlElement element = (XmlElement)node.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//player[@name='{0}']", "Tardis"));
if(element == null)
{
    element = node.CreateElement("player");
    element .SetAttribute("name", "Tardis");
    node.AppendChild(element);
    xmlfile.Save("FileName.xml");
    XmlElement newElement = new Element();
    newElement = node.CreateElement("Kills");
    newElement.Value = 0;
    element.AppendChild(newElement);
    newElement = node.CreateElement("Deaths");
    newElement.Value = 0;
    element.AppendChild(newElement);
    xmlfile.Save("FileName.xml");
}
else
{
    kills = element.FirstChild.Value;
    deaths = element.LastChild.Value;
}
```

Comment: Why are you looking for `element` for the second time when you already have it?

Comment: CreateElement is a method of XmlDocument, not XmlNode

Answer (score 0):

```
        int k = 0, d = 0; //kills and deaths

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        var elem = doc.XPathSelectElement("/SimpleKD/player[@name='Tardis']");

        if (elem != null)
        {
            var killsNode = (XElement)elem.FirstNode;
            k = (int)killsNode;

            var deathsNode = (XElement)killsNode.NextNode;
            d = (int)deathsNode;
        }
        else
        {
            elem = doc.XPathSelectElement("/SimpleKD");
            elem.Add(new XElement("player",
                               new XAttribute("name", "Tardis"),
                           new XElement("kills", k),
                           new XElement("deaths", d)));
        }

        xmlString = doc.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("Kills: {0}", k);
        Console.WriteLine("Deaths: {0}", d);
```

Comment: Why the `//` in your XPath? All it does it to make the code potentially slower and incorrect. And relying on the order of elements (and not checking it!) is not nice.

Answer (score 0):

If the Player is in any part of xml then use simpleKD.Descendants.
If it exists as immediate children then use simpleKD.Elements

```
    private  Player GetPlayer(string name, XElement simpleKD)
    {
        var playerElem = simpleKD.Descendants("player").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.Equals(name));
        if (playerElem == null)
        {
            simpleKD.Add(new XElement("player",
                                      new XAttribute("name", name),
                                      new XElement("kills", 0),
                                      new XElement("deaths", 0)));
            return new Player(name);
        }

        return new Player(name, 
                          (int)playerElem.Element("kills"),
                          (int)playerElem.Element("deaths"));

    }

    class Player
    {
        public string Kills { get; set; }
        public string Deaths { get; set; }
        public Player() { }
        public Player(string name) { }
        public Player(string name, int kills, int deaths) { }
    }
```